# How to get ℅ from a column in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table called `students` with a column `marks`, the data in the `marks` column is like `80,90,70%,50%,30`.
How do I get the data from `marks` column which is like `70%,50%.`

Comment: You can use wildcard in where clause 'LIKE *%'

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I think you should use de escape character: like '%/%'

Comment: @JuanN yeah It should be escape character..I typed * by mistake :p

Comment: The character in the title is [℅ (c/o)](http://unicode-table.com/en/2105/) - is that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data type of marks is varchar.

```
 select marks from students where marks like'%\%' escape '\';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape `%` sing within `WHERE` clause.

Try following

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE marks LIKE '70[%]%' 
OR marks LIKE '50[%]%'
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. `LIKE` doesn't support the "range operator" `[..]`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM students(
WHERE marks LIKE '%\%')
/
```

In above code first % will be treated as wildcard which means it will try to find any character.
Next % is actual string '%' (since it has escape character '/').
So query will return any character followed by '%'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` operator,

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE marks LIKE '\%%'
```